# Can I create an attribute which will be stripped out of release code?

Tags: c#, debugging, attributes, debug-symbols

I want to do something like this:

```
[Notes("Remember to blah blah blah")]
public class Foo {

  [Notes("Redo this to include blah blah")]
  public string Bar { get; set; }

  // etc.

}
```

I know about the `ConditionalAttribute`, but it's sealed so I can't subclass my `NotesAttribute` from it.

Can this be done?

Comment: Could you not simply write a attributes that does nothing? It's obviously just for your own docuumentatio, I'll write //TODO: but if you want to have it with attributes, ok. Now what should your attribute do? nothing? then you have it :)

Comment: Normally I would use a system like TFS to keep track of work to do... This seems like as bad idea.

Comment: @PeterBons We don't use TFS. This seems like a good idea for us.

Comment: @FlorianBurel Yes a no-op attribute is a valid option. But I want to know if the above can be done somehow. BTW this is better than comments in our case because we can reflect over the codebase and run reports. We already use a no-op attribute, but I want to try strip it out of the release build.

Comment: Unexplained downvote, nice.

Comment: @FlorianBurel Found a cool way to do this, see my answer. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this can be done!

See my [related question and answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38990337/3959480).

You need to do this:

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
public class NotesAttribute : Attribute { }
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to use preprocessors:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx

```
#if DEBUG
[Notes("Remember to blah blah blah")]
#endif
public class Foo {

    [Notes("Redo this to include blah blah")]
    public string Bar { get; set; }

    // etc.

}
```

Comment: @hbob it sure is :-) But to completely strip it out from release code there are not that many options. At least not that I know of :-P

Comment: Found a nice way to do this!! See my answer.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the source code of `ConditionalAttribute` from here:

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/diagnostics/conditionalattribute.cs

You then just copy the code and rename the class and you've got your attribute.

Comment: I don't think it's that easy. The compiler know to specifically deal with `ConditionalAttribute` in a special way. The attribute's source doesn't do anything special, so it must be a compiler thing.